# Print a member of struct that is a pointer to another struct?

Tags: c, struct, printf

```
typedef struct Monom{
    int coeficient;
    int exponent;
    struct Monom* Next;
    }Monom;

typedef struct list_polinom{
    struct Monom* First_element;
    }list_polinom;

int main(){
    struct list_polinom* Polinoms;
    struct Monom* Monoms;
    Polinoms = (struct list_polinom*)malloc( x * sizeof(struct list_polinom));
    Monoms = (struct Monom*)malloc(y * sizeof(stuct Monom));
    Polinoms[0].First_element = &Monoms[z];
    Monoms[z].exponent = x;
    return 0;
    }
```

So i want to print `printf("%d\n",Polinoms[0].First_element.exponent`) but i got this error:

> [Error] request for member 'exponent' in something not a structure or union

what am I doing wrong?

Note: x, y ,z are integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the structure and union member access through pointer operator (`->`)

```
 printf("%d\n",Polinoms[0].First_element->exponent);
                                       ^^
```

as `First_element` is a pointer type.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).